# How to make Visual Studio 2017 hit breakpoints when running tests through NUnit GUI 0.60?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, nunit-3.0

I'm attempting to debug an NUnit 3 test from Visual Studio 2017 by using `Project Properties -> Debug -> Start External Program = <path to nunit-gui.exe>`. I can just use the NUnit Test runner from within Visual Studio--that works fine. I can also run NUnit GUI first, load the DLL, and then attach to the `nunit-agent-x86.exe` process and the breakpoints work. However, I'd like to just be able to click the "Start" button from within visual Studio without going through those extra steps.

NUnit GUI does start and I'm able to run the test. However, when I set breakpoints in Visual Studio, they don't get hit (mousing over the breakpoint yields a popover with the message, "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."). In the past, under NUnit 2.6, I fixed this by modifying the `nunit-gui.exe.config`:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
<!-- <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> -->
</startup>
```

However, this still doesn't seem to fix the breakpoint issue in [NUnit GUI 0.60](https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-experimental-gui/releases).

My test assembly platform target is x86 (due to x86 dependencies). I'm running my test on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: There is no such thing. BTW, which VS edition do you use? Community and above does have Test Explorer built-in.

Comment: There is such a thing. I added link.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017:

1. In the top menu open the Test Explorer window via Test > Windows > Test Explorer.
2. Rebuild the solution.
3. Set a breakpoint in the test you want to debug
4. Left click on the "blue diamond" icon between `[Test]` and the `public void` method definition.
5. Left click Debug.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the Visual Studio Test Runner works just fine--I can debug with it. My question is about NUnit GUI 0.60.